# How to print 2 texts in two columns

Tags: text-processing, columns, text-formatting

I have 2 text in different files `file1` and `file2`. I need a command that takes `file1` and `file2` as arguments and print on terminal

```
This is text 1. This is              This is text 2. This is
text 1.This is text 1. This          text 2.This is text 2. This
is text 1. This is text 1.           is text 2. This is text 2. 
This is text 1.                      This is text 2.
```

Comment: `vim -O file1 file2 -c 'windo set scb'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For columns of size 10 distant of 20 characters

```
paste <(fold file1 -w 10) <(fold file2 -sw 10)  | pr -t -e20
```

- `fold` options

  - `-w` is the column width
  - `-s` avoid having separated words from line to line
- `pr` options

  - `-t`  leads to omit header and footer (date, time and page number)
  - `-eN` set `N` to be the number of spaces replacing the tab produced by `paste`